# How to focus images using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two images and textbox on my HTML page I want my first image to be focused whenever i am typing 3 as first character in textbox, second Image to be focused for 4 and so on......

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetChar (event){
        var chCode = ('charCode' in event) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
          if (chCode == 51 /* + */)
          {

             document.getElementById("logo").focus();
             document.getElementById("logo1").blur();
          }

          if (chCode == 52)
          {

             document.getElementById("logo").blur();
             document.getElementById("logo1").focus();
          }

    }
</script>
```

```
  <img id="logo" src="abc.png" alt=""/>
 <img id="logo1" src="def.png" alt=""/>
<input size="40" value="Write a character into this field!" onkeypress="GetChar (event);"/>
```

Comment: So what is not happening ?

Comment: what is the problem..?

Comment: My images are not getting focussed

Comment: you cant focus images

Comment: yes i cant focus image

Comment: @DhirajShukla yes, you cant focus images in HTML/ JS :-) You can only focus input elements.

Comment: I want bubbling effect on my image

Comment: You can't .focus() an image like that.. you'll need to use some form of CSS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can set **tabIndex** property to "0" for image that has typed id instead of focus.

Answer (score -1):

Try using images in INPUT like

```
<INPUT type="image" id="logo" src="abc.png" />
<INPUT type="image" id="logo" src="def.png" />
```